# Expected pseudo-inverse of isotropic random matrix

Tags: random-matrices, matrix-inverse

Suppose I have a random $m \times m$ matrix $R \sim \mu$ that is possibly singular. Is it true that
$ E[R] \propto I$ implies that there exists a scalar $r_{\mu, m}$ such that $E[R^+] = r_{\mu, m}I$, where ${}^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse?

If this is false but there are certain conditions that are needed to make this true, then I'd be interested to know those conditions.

For instance it is true when $R = X^\top X$ and $X$ is $n \times m$ normally distributed (at least I have found references for this when $n\not\in [m-3, m+1]$). Not sure if this is the only non-trivial case.

Comment: what does $R\sim \mu$ mean?

Comment: The random matrix $R$ has distribution $\mu$.

Comment: you write $R^+ = r_{\mu, m}I$ --- don't you want to take the expectation value of $R^+$ ?

Comment: yes, that's a typo! thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general no.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent scalar random variables satisfying $\mathbb E X = \mathbb E Y = 1$ but $\mathbb E X^{-1} \neq \mathbb E Y^{-1}$, then the matrix $R = \begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \\ 0 & Y \end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample.